# Cordova: Using cordova-plugin-file 3.0.0 "File"

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I write a cordova application for iOS. All my files have to reside in `Library/NoCloud` or `Documents/NoCloud` (one requirement local files may not be synchronized, neither to cloud or any backup).

In cordova's config.xml I have put the following files:

```
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
<preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="documents-nosync" />
```

I also tried with

```
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
<preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library-nosync" />
```

Next I request a filesystem using the following Javascript code:

```js
window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 1024 * 1024 * 20, onInitFs, fileErrorHandler);
```

This call succeeds and I store the filesystem in a global variable. Next, I try to check if a directory exists using the following code:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(directoryToCreate, resolveLocalFileSystemURLcallBackExists, onDirectoryExistsFail);

function resolveLocalFileSystemURLcallBackExists(path){
    try {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory(path, { create: false }, onDirectoryExistsSuccess, onDirectoryExistsFail);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Now when I debug the iOS project at some point the following Objective-C code is called:

```c
- (NSString *)fullPathForFileSystemPath:(NSString *)fsPath
{
    if ([fsPath hasPrefix:self.fsRoot]) {
        return [fsPath substringFromIndex:[self.fsRoot length]];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

This function returns always `nil` as `fs.root` points to `/var/.../Libriry/files` and my `directoryToCreate` is `file:///var/.../Library/NoCloud/mydir` or `file:///var/.../Documents/NoCloud/mydir`.

Cordova version: 5.1.1

File plugin version: 3.0.0

How to write to `file:///var/.../Library/NoCloud/` instead of the `files` subfolder?

Comment: looks like a bug, can you file an issue on http://issues.cordova.io/?